# Unboxing may produce NullPointerException

Tags: android, error-handling

I get for next code

```
final boolean isOnList = myList.get(l.Id);
```

***error message*** :

> "Unboxing of myList.get(l.Id) may produce NullPointerException".

MyList is :

```
private Map<String, Boolean> myList = new HashMap<>();
```

and l is:

```
 ActivityHome.Lists l = myList.get(position);
```

I have tried all proposed solutions but still get this error. Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Hi Nick, the error message is pretty self explanatory, the way you have your code designed means 'myList.get(position);' can be null. you need to design your code better. Here is an answer for the question you asked https://stackoverflow.com/a/49788177/5517088

Comment: Can't use that solution because I don't have getInt, the only option is get. I see that moderators compare just titles and ignore the body question. I already mentioned that I tested all proposed solutions from here. So in my opinion is not a duplicated question.

Comment: it is an exact duplicate. your code has an error because it is possible for `myList.get(position);` to be null, exactly like the other question. you need to redesign your code so that it isn't possible to have a nullpointerException.

Comment: I found another way: final boolean isOnList = Objects.requireNonNull(myList.get(l.Id));   And my code is designed to can't get a null;

Comment: ```Boolean isOnList = myList.get(l.Id);
return isOnList != null ? isOnList : false;```
Since Map.getObject, returns an object, you have to check that object against null first. If it is not null, use its value otherwise return false. I believe from API 24, you can provide a default value as well.